# What is the best way to inject a non-View Service in SwiftUI that can be used in other Views or Services?

Tags: swiftui, dependency-injection, service, factory, resolver

Using Swift-5.6.1, iOS-15.6,

Simple question - but not easy answer:

What is the best way to inject a non-View Service in SwiftUI that can be used in other Views or Services ?

We all know how to create and use `@StateObject`, `@ObservableObject` or `@EnvironmentObject` (explained for example [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views) or [here](https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/environmentobject/)).

And we all know that in a View we can instantiate a `StateObject` and inject it to the View-Hierarchy basically anywhere in the App by adding the modifier `.environmentObject(InstantiatedView())` to a View.

And those `@EnvironmentObjects` can then be used anywhere in the View-hierarchy in any SubViews - or basically anywhere in the App.

But what if we are dealing with a Service and not a View ?

What if we want to use this Service in other Views but ALSO IN OTHER SERVICES ???

Is there anything comparable to an `ObservableObject` that can be used in a non-View Service ? If yes, how is it injected ?

- And yes, I know that there are Singleton Objects. But isn't there anything more SwiftUI-like, other than Singleton Classes for this ??
- And yes, I know that there are 3rd party libraries that do exactly what I ask for, such as [Factory](https://github.com/hmlongco/Factory) (a further development of [Resolver](https://github.com/hmlongco/Resolver) explained [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/22203552-resolver-for-ios-dependency-injection-getting-started))

But isn't there anything we can do in pure SwiftUI ???

Comment: Object is an object, it does not matter how do you name it "service" or "view model" or "manager", whichever, you can inject it by reference anywhere and in a whatever way allowed by dependency injection. Optimal way depends on context - there is no one answer.

Comment: @Asperi: can you make an example maybe ? Thank you.

Comment: @Asperi Your comment is a non-answer. What use is iKK supposed to get from that? It's a perfectly valid question, since the "Apple way" with (at)EnvironmentObject only applies to Views.

Comment: @iKK I have been exploring the same. It seems like most people fall back to sending in dependencies through the initializer, but coming from C# and other languages where you have proper automatic self-initializating dependencies, I have also struggled with how to shape it in SwiftUI.

Comment: Further more the (at)EnvironmentObject is not safe. It's runtime executed which mean if you accidentially delete or forget to store the object your app will crash. Proper dependency injection provides compiletime checks of this. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No I have not found any backed-in SwiftUI solution. Still waiting for it.